# Is it idiomatic to say "I'm with development team?"

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage

I saw in many US movies, people say `I'm with the fbi`, so is it idiomatic to say:

- I'm with the development team.
- I heard you have changed team, are you with the infrastructure team now?

Comment: The title of your question doesn't match the body of your question. Are you asking about the use of the article? If not, what is your specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both of those are perfectly normal expressions that will be used and understood by native English speakers.

You can also use that construction when talking about people, particularly when talking about the current moment

> I'm with friends tonight
>   I'm here with my brother

or in a romantic relationship

> I've been with Rebecca for six months now